# how to make my wordpress plugin redirect to form successful page or failed page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have created a plugin that will insert data into my local database.  But upon submission, I want to redirect to a successful page or an unsuccessful page or a duplicate record page.  Below is my plugin code.  When hitting submit the database insert works just fine, but I get a 404 error for the redirect pages.  No errors in php, apache or mysql logs either.

```
<?php
/*
plugin name: deano plugin
description: deano test database to insert data into books table
author: Dean-O

*/
$path = preg_replace('/wp-content.*$/', '', __DIR__);
require_once($path.'/wp-load.php');
function deanoinsertdata() {
/**
* Dean-O database insert book function
*/
global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
    $data=array(
        'wp_id'=>$_POST['wp_id'],
        'title'=>$_POST['title'],
        'author'=>$_POST['author'],
    );
    $table_name = 'books';
    $foundOne = 1;

    $wp_idin = $_POST['wp_id'];
    $titlein = $_POST['title'];
    $authorin = $_POST['author'];

    /*echo ($wp_idin);
    echo ($titlein);
    echo ($authorin);
    */

    /*
    see if the record is already in the table
    */
    $sql = "select * from books"; 
    print $sql;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    foreach($results as $result) {
        if($result->wp_id==$wp_idin && $result->title==$titlein && $result->author==$authorin)
        {
            $foundOne = 0;
        }
    }

    if($foundOne==1) {
        $resultinsert = $wpdb->insert($table_name,$data, $format=NULL);
        if($resultinsert==1) {
             //header('Location: http://localhost/tadpolewp/deano-plugin-successful/'); 
            error_log( 'successful' );
             wp_redirect( "http://localhost/tadpolewp/deano-plugin-successful/", 301 );
            //error_log('Book saved 1');
            //echo "Book Saved 1";
        } else {
            //header('Location: http://localhost/tadpolewp/deano-plugin-failed/'); 
            error_log( 'failed to save' );
            wp_redirect( "http://localhost/tadpolewp/deano-plugin-failed/", 301 );
            //error_log('unable to save');
            //echo "Unable to Save";
        }
    } else {
        //error_log('Duplicate record found');
        //echo "Duplicate recortd found";
        //header('Location: http://localhost/tadpolewp/deano-plugin-duplicate-records/');
        error_log( 'duplicate record' );
        wp_redirect( "http://localhost/tadpolewp/deano-plugin--duplicate-records/", 301 );

    }

    

    

}
?>
<form role="form" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                      <?php
                // get current user ID, with default value, if empty
                $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
            ?>

                    <input type="hidden" name="wp_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_user_id ); ?>" />
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Book Title</label>
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_user_id ); ?>" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Book Author</label>
    <input id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Primary Author" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit1" class="btn btn-info btn-block" name="submitbtn">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, do those pages exist? Also, instead of raw headers, WordPress has functions for redirects, either `wp_safe_redirect` or `wp_redirect`.

Comment: yes the pages exist.

Comment: I tried. wp_redirect( "http://localhost/tadpolewp/deano-plugin-successful/", 301 ); and changed the other ones to point the their pages, and still get the 404 page.  Those pages are restricted pages to logged in people.  The page that plugin is on is also a restricted page.  I am logged in as a regular user and the plugin page comes up, the data is saved to the database, but the page redirects give me a 404 error

Comment: So ignoring the redirect and insert stuff, do the pages 404 when you refresh and/or go to them normally?

Comment: as a logged in user I can get to them without the 404 error

Answer (score 0):

my bad... I forgot the exit();  after each redirect.  Problem solved.